# How to setup a git repository on local network?

Tags: git

How do I setup git on a machine on my LAN so that other developers can commit to my machine?

Comment: See also https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a repo with `git init` on machine A
2. Clone it from another machine B with

   ```
   git clone username@machineB.ip.address.here:path/to/git/repo/here.git
   ```

   this may prompt you for login credentials for machine B.

That's all. If you do `git remote -v` on machine B now, you will see that the remote repo is located at machine A

Answer (score 3):

From a terminal on the machine to act as the "git server", assumed to be "your machine":

```
cd ~
mkdir git && cd git
mkdir my-project && cd my-project
git init --bare --shared
exit
```

On the developer machines:

```
git clone <USERNAME>@<IP_ADDRESS>:git/my-project
```

Notes: I would suggest creating a new user on your machine called "git", you can also clone from your usual username, like the other developers, too.